# Find the maximum spanning the tree of a connected weighted graph

Tags: algorithm

How can I ﬁnd the maximum spanning the tree of a connected weighted graph, that is, the spanning tree of the largest total weight?

Comment: multiply each weight by -1. Now problem is reduced to classic minimum spanning tree problem, just use Prim/Kruskal/etc

Answer (score 1):

Another way to find the maximum spanning tree would be to use Kruskal's algorithm. Just like Prim's algorithm, Kruskal's algorithm is a commonly used algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree.

The only change needed to be made in Kruskal's algorithm is that instead of ordering the edges in ascending order, order the edges in descending order (the edge with the heaviest weight would come first) into a list L.

The rest of the algorithm would be the same: initially, the maximum spanning tree T would be an empty set. There would be equivalence classes, each of them containing individual vertex of the graph. Then, repeat the following procedures while there is more than one equivalence class:
Remove the first edge in the list L. Then, if the two vertices of the edge are not in the same equivalence class, the edge would be included in the maximum spanning tree T and the equivalence classes of the two vertices would be replaced with the union of the equivalence classes of the two vertices.

In the end, T would contain edges that form the maximum spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm): choose any vertex, then repeatedly choose the best edge among those that connect already-added vertices to not-yet-added vertices. Prim's algorithm is normally described as finding the *minimum* spanning tree, but it works exactly the same way for finding a maximum spanning tree, just with *maximum-weight* edges being "best", rather than *minimum-weight* edges.